# What is the physical limitation of using blood bending (hemokinesis) to make bullets with your own blood?

Tags: super-powers, telekinesis

Recently, I have considered making a character who is able to use what is essentially blood-bending, otherwise known by its more formal name of hemokinesis.

The problem is that this ability has one clear limitation when you are drawing from your own source of blood. There is only so much blood in the human body that can be used before the person kills themselves by using it all.

According to the Blood Calculator I found online (https://www.thecalculator.co/health/Blood-Calculator-67.html), the amount of blood this character should have would be approximately 4.08 liters. Female-170cm tall-65 kg.

This character is able to create and fire bullets of her own blood telepathically. Let's say that a bullet of blood is roughly cylindrical and has an approximate length of 3 cm and radius of 0.5 cm. Using the area formula of a cylinder I get that 3 * 0.5^2 * pi cm^3 worth of blood was used for one bullet. This is approximately 0.75*pi or 2.356 cubic centimeters worth of blood.

*Considering the body weight and height of my character, approximately how many bullets of blood would she be able to create before she started to face serious health consequences due to her ability?*

To clarify, I am specifically asking how many bullets of blood she would be able to extract from her own natural stores before she faces grievous health problems as a result of what is missing.

Edit: We will assume a battle using this power could be anywhere from 15 minutes as a low estimate and as much as 2 hours in length as the high estimate.

This character has had this power since the age of twelve. She is 19 now. The longest she has gone without using it is three months. The longest successive use of her power was at least one battle per day over a two-week timeframe. Her average is at least four to five major battles every month of every year since she got the power, leading to a total of about 400 battles in her lifetime.

Edit2: To answer a question about reload time I would say she can make a new bullet every 1-3 seconds and she can sustain each individual bullet she creates for as long as she needs them.

Edit3: I have erased the section about 2% loss as I have deemed it irrelevant.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. The shortest battle sequence is approximately 15 minutes long. The longest is a long-term tense battle that takes place over 2 hours. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Another clarification: how often is she firing blood bullets during a given time period? Say 15 minutes. In other words, is she a sniper firing maybe one or two, or is she just randomly spraying these things at two hundred a minute?

Comment: Related:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/120592/how-to-build-a-blood-gun

Comment: Just a thought reading through, why if you could bend blood, would you make bullets of your own? (apart from it being cool af), if she has the ability to bend blood outside her own body (to maintain the bullets) couldn't she just give every enemy an embolism or heartattack?

Comment: The density of blood is on the order of 1/10 that of bullets, depending on the bullet material. You'll want to compensate for that somehow, as both momentum and kinetic energy are directly proportional to mass. I assume the bending would compensate for the poor ballistic characteristics of low-density projectiles.

Comment: what's the logic for the 2% loss? If she can move the blood back from the victim to her body, what is preventing her to move it from the floor to her body?

Comment: @Ivo Beckers I have had people tell me that part was irrelevant so I have decided to edit that part out.

Comment: Since she’s controlling the substance, it doesn’t need to be spin or fin stabilized, so instead of bullets, use flechettes. They’re a third of the weight of a bullet of similar ‘size’.

Answer (score 13):

##### "How much blood can this patient afford to lose..."

This was a trick ~ not trick question a wise surgeon used to ask medical students. It's a trick question because, indeed, a person can stand to lose some blood without long term effects. It's a not trick question because we're not really designed to lose blood, and it doesn't take a lot of blood loss to cause problems.

Without knowing a lot of specifics about your character (and thus risking a rather curious case of blood related story based questioning) I'd stick with some generalities.

People donate blood all the time, and people get cut and bleed all the time. Since people don't regularly die after giving a unit of blood, there must be some amount of padding. Since this varies by person, and it's not a quantity you ever want to discover about yourself, I'm going to remain well on the safe side of the line.

There are several levels of hemorrhage. 1 through 4, [according to this article](https://www.medicaldaily.com/breaking-point-how-much-blood-can-human-body-lose-350792).

**Class 1** is a blood loss less than 15% of the total volume. Donating blood easily falls in this category. A typical donation is about 10%, so about 400cc for your character. **That's 170 bullets**.

**Class 2** is a blood loss of 15% to 30% of total volume. This is survivable, but not an ideal situation to be in. She'll feel weak and probably a little light headed. Not a good situation for a warrior to be in during a fight. 30% is 1200cc or **509 bullets**.

**Class 3** is a blood loss of 30% to 40% of total volume. She'll need a blood transfusion if she pushes herself this far. 40% is 1600cc or **679 bullets**. She will most likely fall unconscious at this point.

**Class 4** is a blood loss of over 40% of total volume. This is pretty much fatal without immediate access to critical intervention. The loss is so great that body systems can no longer be supported, including the brain. Things just shut down and she'll die. If your character were able to squeeze out a few more bullets, perhaps as a last ditch effort to go down fighting, she might be able to use 50% of her total volume for bullets. That's 2000cc or **849 bullets**.

I'm disregarding the 2% loss rate as irrelevant. The blood is gone from her body, so it doesn't really matter if some ends up on the floor or ends up on the wall next to her target.

**Conclusion**: Hemokinesis is an interesting idea, but from a tactical / military / warrior culture perspective, it's really dumb! Blood isn't something you want to willingly give away, especially in a fight, unless she's really at the ultimate extremity and she's going to die any and has made the choice to take out as many enemies as she can.

I'd argue that your blood blasting warrior girl can ***"safely"*** expend no more than 170 bullets during any engagement. Whether that's a fifteen skirmish or a battle lasting a week. In the extreme, and if she's a valuable asset, then I think it could be argued that she could double that over a period of time and that she should be made to rest and given volume replenishment treatment (IV fluids).

She could survive more, but that would be a waste.

---

It was always a pleasure to watch as said medical students tried to follow the same calculations you did to arrive at a particular number. The answer to the question, by the way, is "none".

Comment: Also if she shoots bullets on an empty stomach, she may regret it even at the lowest level.  OTOH there are blood diseases that require blood letting to survive, which could help, though she would be sick.

Comment: @Mary --- Indeed. Therapeutic phlebotomy only removes about as much blood as an ordinary donation and is done every two to four months. If our warrior girl is scheduled for her regular treatment, she can "safely" fire the same 170 bullets!

Comment: I like this answer, except for the conclusion. In fact, if the character can bend other people's blood, the case could be made that she only needs to fire 1 bullet from her own blood. She can then use the supply from the dead victim for the remainder of the fight with no ill-effects to herself.

Comment: As someone who doesn't know much - would the bullet counts be higher if the character could craft specific parts of their blood? Like would it be ideal to take only plasma at first, or just the red blood cells (or something else), as opposed to equal proportions on all of it?

Comment: "The other 98% goes back into her body after she is using it" This makes a huge difference, especially over large timeframes ("Whether that's a fifteen skirmish or a battle lasting a week.")

Comment: @DoubleDouble "blood bullets" are so weird to start with that I don't think you could usefully generalize about how it works.

Comment: I will add that I did the calculation on mass rather than volume, using the **5.56 NATO** M193 bullet for reference which comes in at 3.56 g, and the result is **191 bullets** for 15% of blood (assuming 7% of a 65kg human is blood). If you fired that through a M16A4 which fires such rounds, that'd last you about *14 seconds*.

Comment: @QuantumMecha --- I'm pleased as blood pudding punch you like this answer! As for using someone else's blood, I'd agree! Theoretically, all she'd have to do is use ***all the blood from all her enemies*** to make bullets! All of her enemies would be dead within seconds thus problems solved! The query, however specifies **make bullets with (her)  own blood?** Hence the conclusion.

Comment: @DoubleDouble --- No. The underlying physics is simply a matter of volume: in other words, she has a set volume of blood and it doesn't matter what she uses first. She runs into a problem if she use plasma first as that's the medium all the cells slosh around in. Take away the plasma and she'll end up with a massive clot. If she uses the cells first, she'd run into issues of compromised gas exchange much sooner.

Comment: @fectin --- Interesting: Since it's our job to make sense of the senseless and generalise about the weird I'd be curious to see you expand on your comment.

Comment: @elemtilas sure: the blood is being shaped and moved somehow, and is not behaving at all like blood. It’s also punching through people on impact, not just splattering. So starting from an arbitrary set of laws being suspended in an arbitrary way, it is very hard to something outside the givens from the question.

Comment: @AmiralPatate --- That's an excellent point to bear in mind! And +1 for it! Regardless of any physiological considerations, she'll run out of blood bullets  long before she runs out of battle (unless she participated in the megapantagruelian Battle of Ashtar IX in which the star fleets of no fewer than fourteen star empire took part in the epic battle that lasted all of 647ms when the nearby star went supernova, making the entire prospect moot).

Comment: @elemtilas for example, Doubledouble asks about just using plasma. But that gets to the deeper question of what makes it “her blood” for the purpose of this. Can she use transfused blood? Transfused saline? Add a drop of her blood to the ocean and use the entire ocean? What about smearing a small quantity on a regular lead bullet? As soon as you get outside the basic “this much blood, pulled from a normal body, is a bullet” you are totally in the realm of speculation.

Comment: @fectin --- Okay, I think I understand your perspective. That's the kind of stuff we deal in here! To your specific point, I'd only say that once the blood is removed from her body via hemokinesis, it becomes beyond the scope of the question! **How does a blood bullet work, anyway?** would be a good follow up question!

Comment: @elemtilas I like this answer, by the way. I think it answers as much as you can without extrapolating.

Comment: @fectin---"Her blood" means the blood currently in her circulatory system. We're not given any conditions beyond those in the query, so we can really only assume that "her blood" is what her body produced and is currently in her vessels. Questions of using transfused blood, the ocean, &c are all excellent follow up queries! Those become questions of the magic system itself and are all highly interesting!

Comment: @fectin --- That's the highest praise one can hope for here and for this kind of question.  I'd note that using the ocean is quite the philosophical inquiry as, in a very real sense, our blood really is a little bit of ocean we carry around inside ourselves, ever since the first fully enclosed lifeforms came along!

Answer (score 2):

Blood loss aside, I would question the properties of your 'blood bullet' itself.

A liquid 'bullet' would simply splash against a target, and wouldn't damage the offender in any measurable way. If you hit them in the eyes or mouth you could inflict blood transmissible illness, but I don't know if that's what you're after.

While that bullet is in flight, if it's reaching supersonic speeds it would be reasonable to assume that the leading edge could heat up above 100 degrees C due to frictional forces in the air (this assumption is loosely based on aircraft like Concorde which regularly saw temperatures of 100+ on the nose cone when in flight). While the blood bullet has a smaller surface area and likely would undergo less heating during flight, it would still likely evaporate fairly quickly, and if not the friction of the air would probably atomise the fluid itself anyway.

If the blood bullet is frozen, however, it may have a chance of not evaporating before hitting the target. I believe mythbusters tried this concept with a water ice bullet, however from memory they had issues with it shattering in their barrel when firing. Your magic blood bullet likely won't have this problem, but it may also shatter when impacting the target unless it's travelling at an extremely high velocity - in which case it would have problems with melting due to friction with the air as mentioned above.

That all being said, if the bullet remains magically entwined during it's flight and is able to retain all it's properties up until the point of penetration, then these comments are moot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was an edit in the original post after 'elemtilas' provided their detailed answer, but it looks like the 2% loss isn't as insignificant as assumed. From the post, I understand that the blood that's used for a bullet returns to the character's body once the bullet has done its work/damage, with a 2% loss.

Using the numbers from the aforementioned answer, if we assume the bullets are made and used one by one (to provide them with the psychokinetic energy required to overcome the limitations mentioned by 'Aaron Lavers'), only 2% of the volume of a bullet is lost for each, so the amounts can be multiplied by 50 with about the same side-effects as already described:

- 170 --> 8500 bullets with relative ease/safety
- 509 --> 25450 bullets with the effect of becoming weaker and light headed
- 679 --> 33950 bullets after which she'd need transfusions
- 849 --> 42450 bullets after which she bites the dust

If using your enemies blood is also an option as suggested by 'AmiralPatate', you're getting even closer to an unlimited amount than already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

#### Unlimited

This outrageous answer comes courtesy of the calculation having already been made correctly, thus I'm left with the other obvious answer that your problem is using your blood when you can use...

**THE BLOOD OF YOUR ENEMY!**

There wasn't any qualification that using other sources of blood was forbidden after all, so this is still technically correct.

Now, to be perfectly accurate, the answer isn't "unlimited" because you will likely run out of enemies. But if you run out of enemies, you also don't need bullets, so practically unlimited.

Taking the calculation from @elemtilas, if 50% of a human's blood is 849 bullets, I think we can conservatively estimate that you could take a thousand bullets out of every enemy you turn into a corpse on average.

This assumes you can use the blood of people who no longer need it. If you could use the blood of live creatures other than yourself, at that point, you might just drain them of blood and skip the bullet-making part. If you can't do neither, obviously just buy a gun.